# Cannot find variable component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I keep getting this error

[image]

What I have tried:
-restarting the npm

installing the npm latest version

Checked all my classes extends Component is missing in neither of them

my code:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View,ScrollView}from 'react-native'
import{createBottomTabNavigator,createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import{createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import{Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import Home from './Home';
import WishList from './WishList';
import Settings from './Settings';
import Profile from './Profile'
import Cart from './Cart'


 class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const TabNavigator=createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home:{screen:Home,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Home',
        activeColor:'#ff0000',
        inactivecolor:'#000000',
        barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
        tabBarIcon:()=>(
          <View>
            <Icon name= {'home'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
          </View>
        )
      }
    },
    WishList:{screen:WishList,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'WishList',
        activeColor:'#ff0000',
        inactivecolor:'#000000',
        barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
        tabBarIcon:()=>(
          <View>
            <Icon name= {'favorite'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
          </View>
        )
      }
    },
    Cart:{screen:Cart,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Cart',
        activeColor:'#ff0000',
        inactivecolor:'#000000',
        barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
        tabBarIcon:()=>(
          <View>
            <Icon name= {'add-shopping-cart'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
          </View>
        )
      }
  },
  Profile:{screen:Profile,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Profile',
      activeColor:'#ff0000',
      inactivecolor:'#000000',
      barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
      tabBarIcon:()=>(
        <View>
          <Icon name= {'person'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
        </View>
      )
    }
  },
  Settings:{screen:Settings,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Settings',
      activeColor:'#ff0000',
      inactivecolor:'#000000',
      barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
      tabBarIcon:()=>(
        <View>
          <Icon name= {'settings'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
        </View>
      )
    }
},
  }
)
export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

I also kept searching for my mistake on stack overflow but the answer did not helped me as i am still stuck with this error any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Just to make sure that's the cause, try replacing `Component` with `React.Component` (i.e. `class App extends React.Component`)

Comment: @Chris should i do it with main class only or all of them?

Comment: I'd try to create a minimal app first, and see if that change fixes the problem. Don't change it for every component yet, simply remove references to them until you have a running app on your phone.